# Tor: Relay configuration issue "Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:443: Permission denied"

Tags: tor

**sudo service tor reload**

```
 * Reloading tor daemon configuration...      [fail]
```

/var/log/tor/log

```
Jan 08 08:01:25.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 (git-605ae665009853bd) opening new log file.
Jan 08 10:19:40.000 [notice] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 3 days 0:00 hours, with 0 circuits open. I've sent 1.17 MB and received 28.04 MB.
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [notice] Received reload signal (hup). Reloading config and resetting internal state.
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 5988 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [warn] **Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:443: Permission denied**
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above. For usage, try -h.
Jan 08 12:31:58.000 [warn] Restart failed (config error?). Exiting.
```

Configuration /etc/tor/torrc

```
ORPort 443
Nickname ididnteditheconfig
RelayBandwidthRate 1000 KBytes  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
RelayBandwidthBurst 2000 KBytes # But allow bursts up to 200KB (1600Kb)
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

Opened 443 port on the Internet box:
[image]

Port 443 locally opened:
**ss -tunlp | grep 443**

```
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                    *:443                   *:*     
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                   :::443                  :::*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind lower ports without root permission.

You have to do this to do so.

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /path/to/binary
```

For me it worked fine but there are also other ways.

> **For more Information and a better explanation read this.**
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443